# Recovery specific directory from a deleted partition

Tags: disk, recovery, file-recovery, diskimage

I know that this question is very common, but sometimes are special cases.

I used `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=4M` to fix a HDD with many badblocks. (I`m using Ubuntu live USB).

All 8 partitions (3 of them are big, 1 windows, 1 linux, and 1 to storage) were lost.

I`d like to try to recovery at least the storage partition or even some specifics directories within.

I tried grep on /dev/sda with -a option but I got this error `grep: memory exhausted`.

Also, I'm not able to install foremost or ddrescue. For this last one I got this message

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f ddrescue-gui
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ddrescue-gui : Depends: python3-wxgtk4.0 but it is not installable
                Depends: gddrescue but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But even to install lzip I`m getting errors.

At least 1 recent folder I need to getting from there.

Would you help me?
thanks in advance

Comment: Just to get it straight: you wiped your HDD with data to fix it?

Comment: @emix was quiet it exactly, so, does `/dev/zero` write up all data?

Comment: Well `/dev/zero` are just nulls. Basically you zeroed every bit of the data on your disk. Good job :D